# Calculating variations in sampling frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sequence of timestamps (in Unix milliseconds timebase) stored in a pandas Series. Each timestamp belongs to a sensor measurement. To get the sampling frequency I can just subtract the last timestamp from the first one and then divide by the amount of timestamps:

```
# assuming df is my Series
sf = (df.iloc[-1] - df.iloc[1]) / len(df)
```

But this does not provide me insights about the variation of the sampling frequency.

How can I calculate the standard deviation of the sampling frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the timestamps stored in numerical form, I'd propose simply checking the std of the interval between two timestamps.

In your example:

```
df.diff().std()
```